# Is it possible to generate a certificate fully in BMPString encoding?

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, asn.1

While creating certificates using openssl command, I'm using a custom config file like this:

```
prompt = no
distinguished_name = dn
req_extensions = ext
string_mask = pkix

[dn]
CN = распространенное имя
emailAddress = envek@envek.com
O = Организация
OU = SSL Test
L = Москва
C = RU

[ext]
subjectAltName = DNS:BMPString.com,DNS:*.BMPString.com
```

Now when I do asn1parse using this command:

**openssl asn1parse -in bmp.crt -i -strparse 200**

```
    0:d=0  hl=3 l= 243 cons: SEQUENCE
    3:d=1  hl=2 l=  87 cons:  SET
    5:d=2  hl=2 l=  85 cons:   SEQUENCE
    7:d=3  hl=2 l=   3 prim:    OBJECT            :commonName
   12:d=3  hl=2 l=  78 prim:    BMPSTRING
   92:d=1  hl=2 l=  30 cons:  SET
   94:d=2  hl=2 l=  28 cons:   SEQUENCE
   96:d=3  hl=2 l=   9 prim:    OBJECT            :emailAddress
  107:d=3  hl=2 l=  15 prim:    IA5STRING         :envek@envek.com
  124:d=1  hl=2 l=  53 cons:  SET
  126:d=2  hl=2 l=  51 cons:   SEQUENCE
  128:d=3  hl=2 l=   3 prim:    OBJECT            :organizationName
  133:d=3  hl=2 l=  44 prim:    BMPSTRING
  179:d=1  hl=2 l=  17 cons:  SET
  181:d=2  hl=2 l=  15 cons:   SEQUENCE
  183:d=3  hl=2 l=   3 prim:    OBJECT            :organizationalUnitName
  188:d=3  hl=2 l=   8 prim:    PRINTABLESTRING   :SSL Test
  198:d=1  hl=2 l=  33 cons:  SET
  200:d=2  hl=2 l=  31 cons:   SEQUENCE
  202:d=3  hl=2 l=   3 prim:    OBJECT            :localityName
  207:d=3  hl=2 l=  24 prim:    BMPSTRING
  233:d=1  hl=2 l=  11 cons:  SET
  235:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 cons:   SEQUENCE
  237:d=3  hl=2 l=   3 prim:    OBJECT            :countryName
  242:d=3  hl=2 l=   2 prim:    PRINTABLESTRING   :RU
```

CN, OrganizationName, LocalityName are all in BMPString but not OrganizationalUnitName.

I understand the logic as all characters come under the umbrella of PrintableString in OrganizationalUnitName and that's why it's been encoded in the same.

But I want to automatically encode "PrintableString" characters in BMPString, is that possible?

Edit 1: Changed "except" to "but not".

Edit 2: Removed Email from "CN, Email, OrganizationName, LocalityName are all in BMPString but not OrganizationalUnitName."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> CN, Email, OrganizationName, LocalityName are all in BMPString except OrganizationalUnitName

Minor: 'except' in English means a subtraction from what is stated previously or in general elsewhere; it's wrong to say 'X except Y' when Y is not included in X. What I belive you mean can properly be stated like "CN, email, Org, Locality are [all] in BMPString **but not** OrgUnit".

Major: email is NOT in BMPString. See below.

For attributes that are defined as `DirectoryString` in the standards, which depending on the version of ASN.1 is either a `CHOICE` type or a macro that expands to a `CHOICE` type, and is used by most of the attributes you have, configuring `string_mask=MASK:0x800` forces them to `BMPString`.

However, the standards require Country *must* be `PrintableString` and email *must* be `IA5String`; these are not defined as `DirectoryString` and are not allowed to be encoded as `BMPString`.

I assume you realize that *PKIX* standards have prohibited BMPString for DN attributes for 18 years, so any software used on the Internet and maintained well enough to be safe to use today should reject your certs. That doesn't prevent you creating them, though.

Comment: Thanks for the edits, much appreciated. I understand email is supposed to be encoded in IAFString. But I want the CN/O/OU to be in BMPString for some testing purpose. I think setting string_mask=MASK:0x800 will work. And can you also tell me mask for T61String?

Comment: Found for T61String at https://docs.huihoo.com/doxygen/openssl/1.0.1c/crypto_2asn1_2asn1_8h_source.html, string_mask=MASK:0x0004. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

RFC 5280 says:

> (c)  TeletexString, BMPString, and UniversalString are included
> for backward compatibility, and SHOULD NOT be used for
> certificates for new subjects.  However, these types MAY be
> used in certificates where the name was previously
> established, including cases in which a new certificate is
> being issued to an existing subject or a certificate is being
> issued to a new subject where the attributes being encoded
> have been previously established in certificates issued to
> other subjects.  Certificate users SHOULD be prepared to
> receive certificates with these types.

You should really avoid BMPString -- it's not well supported.